# Magento 2.3.4 - Get a list of all custom attributes for Categories

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, database, admin

how I can get a list of all custom attributes that exist in backend for Categories? Is there anyway to do it from phpMyAdmin?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all attribute labels and codes in the eav_attribute table.

If you need to find all attributes associated with a specific attribute set you can look in the eav_attribute_set table and find the required attribute_set_id.

Then go to the eav_entity_attribute table and you can filter/search by the attribute_set_id to find all attribute id's associated with that attribute set.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how I can view in the attribute set the categories attributes? my question was how I can have a list with all categories attrbites ...

Comment: Do you mean things like the name and page title of a specific category? If so, then you can find this data in the tables that have the prefix catalog_category_